# numpy - calculate value from matrix indexes

Tags: matrix, numpy

I need to create a new `(n*m) x 4` matrix (e.g. named `b`) from a `n x m` matrix (e.g. named `a`), but I don't want to use nested loops for speed reasons. Here how I would do it with a nested loop:

```
for j in xrange(1,m+1):
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
        index = (j-1)*n+i
        b[index,1] = a[i,j]
        b[index,2] = index
        b[index,3] = s1*i+s2*j+s3
        b[index,4] = s4*i+s5*j+s6
```

The question is, therefore, how to create a new matrix with values derived from original matrix indexes? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the indexing. Say `m=5` and `n=4`, then the value of `index` on the first iteration is `5`. Your loop would set values of `b[5,:]`, leaving `b[0:4,:]` untouched. Is that the intent?

Comment: you are completely right and I am completely sorry: I wrote the code "on the fly" and it's been a little while since I last wrote code :$. However I hope you get the meaning of the question, I simply meant I need to scan the entire matrix with a slow nested loop approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use numpy, you could try

```
import numpy as np
# Create an empty array
b = np.empty((np.multiply(*a.shape), 4), dtype=a.dtype)
# Get two (nxm) of indices
(irows, icols) = np.indices(a)
# Fill the b array
b[...,0] = a.flat
b[...,1] = np.arange(a.size)
b[...,2] = (s1*irows + s2*icols + s3).flat
b[...,3] = (s4*irows + s5*icols + s6).flat
```

Comment: Thank you! I found a similar solution by myself, but this is better

Answer (score 0):

some minor corrections (could not post as comment :/ ) for those who will have a similar question:

```
import numpy as np
# Create an empty array
b = np.empty((a.size, 4), dtype=a.dtype)
# Get two (nxm) of indices (starting from 1)
(irows, icols) = np.indices(a.shape) + 1
# Fill the b array
b[...,0] = a.flat
b[...,1] = np.arange(a.size) + 1 
b[...,2] = (s1*irows + s2*icols + s3).flat
b[...,3] = (s4*irows + s5*icols + s6).flat
```